# Somalia follow-up

Tags: marketplace

Almost two years ago I asked [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2459/bitcoins-somalia).

Now I'm wondering if anything has developed in the mean time.  In particular, are Somalia immigrants to the USA (of whom there are many in Minneapolis) now using bitcoins to send money to their relatives in Somalia?

Comment: I wonder if the lack of proliferation in developing nations is proportional to the lack of hashpower.  Do senders/receivers view it as a security risk to not be able to hash?  Is bandwidth too expensive?  Are clients even available in Somali?  What about Somaliland: they seem to be much further along, and some speak English.  Any news there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the only thing that has really changed is the growth and exposure of Bitcoin. The biggest challenge I see in moving money like this is exchanging or use. How are the Somalia-based recipients going to use the Bitcoins if no in the community is using or exchanging them. For Bitcoin to be used in a money transmitting operation successfully, the community must accept it and use it to a certain degree in order for the Bitcoins to have any value for the Somalian-based receiver. Also you need an internet connection to at least one well known node, even the cheapest slowest internet will suffice if a thin-wallet is used.